# Windows scheduler not executing task

Tags: powershell, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

The below command-line will successfully execute a powershell command invisibly; saving the output to a text file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe C:\temp\invisible.vbs C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -WindowStyle Hidden -command ( (Get-StartApps -Name 'RDP (Tools)').AppID > c:\Temp\AppB.txt )
```

**invisible.vbs:**

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

However, if I create a Windows scheduler task where the Action is: **EXE =** `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` and...

**ARGUMENTS =** `C:\temp\invisible.vbs C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -WindowStyle Hidden -command ( (Get-StartApps -Name 'RDP (Tools)').AppID > c:\Temp\AppB.txt )`

...the text file doesn't get created when I run the scheduler task; even though it says operation completed successfully (0x0).

How can I create a Windows scheduler task that does the same thing as from a command line?

**HINT:**  When I run the scheduled task, a powershell.exe process is spawned by Task Scheduler.  However, it doesn't appear to be doing anything.   Something is causing the PowerShell process to not run as expected.  Unfortunately, I can't tell what's happening.

**HINT2:**  When I completely eliminate the VBScript; where Task Schedule executes only PowerShell; and, the respective command, it works fine.  Unfortunately, I don't know vbscript well enough to know why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you move the command into a ps1 file and use the -File parameter instead?

Comment: Thanks.  But, I already had to make a `invisible.vbs` file dependency; which I really didn't want to do. I don't want to make yet another file dependency for this task.  Ideally, I'd like to do it all without any file dependencies.

Comment: PS:  I just tried moving the PowerShell code to a ps1 file and use the -File parameter.  However, I get the same exact behavior. It looks like there is something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I believe your vbs is only grabbing the first argument. stopping at powershell.exe.  Try surrounding the whole argument with quotes `C:\temp\invisible.vbs "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -WindowStyle Hidden -command ( (Get-StartApps -Name 'RDP (Tools)').AppID > c:\Temp\AppB.txt )"`

Comment: Dan, you're the man!  Thank you!  That's what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

MKNANET,

FWIW: I had no problem running w/o the VBS as follows:

```
Task Scheduler--
  Command: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
  Arguments: -noprofile -WindowStyle Hidden -command  (Get-StartApps -Name "*Office*").AppID >> G:\Test\AppB.txt
```

Note: as I didn't have any 'RDP (Tools)' items in my app list I changed it to look for Office items.

HTH

Comment: Hi @RetiredGeek - the purpose of the vbs script in the middle is to run the task completely quiet which powershell cannot seem to manage on its own even with `-WindowStyle Hidden`.  The window will still flash on screen before being hidden.  The vbs work-around is completely silent.